# How to poll item in Channel Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I am doing baby step on `Channel` **Buffer**. I am learning to **Poll** item through `Channel` . When I send item, it doesn't `receive()` all item. I don't understand why?

```
class QueueViewModel(private val application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val basketChannel = Channel<String>(Channel.UNLIMITED)
    
    init {
        startPolling()
    }

 
    fun addItems() {
        addItemInChannel(100L, "Item 1")
        addItemInChannel(1000L, "Item 2")
        addItemInChannel(400L, "Item 3")
        addItemInChannel(500L, "Item 4")
    }

    fun addItemInChannel(delay: Long, item: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(delay)
            logE("basketChannelItem added -> $item")
            basketChannel.send(item)
        }
    }

    fun startPolling() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            Log.e(TAG, "Starting Polling")
            for (element in basketChannel) {
                logE("basketChannel Item poll -> $element")
                basketChannel.receive()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I called `addItems()` in activity..

**Output**

[image]

where other items gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you get items of your channel in two places: `for` and `receive()`. In general, they work in the same way. According to your log, `for` received items `1` and `4`, while `receive()` method got `2` and `3`.

You can remove `basketChannel.receive()` line, and you will receive all elements in `for` loop